# Rodar comando - Terminal

Tags: script, cmd, terminal

**Lembrando que isso não é apenas para este caso, quero criar por exemplo .bats para automatizar algumas coisas, então gostaria de saber como fazê-lo aguardar o retorno de comandos e interpretar a minha próxima linha como resposta.**

Como posso fazer o arquivo .bat responder uma pergunta vem de um comando, por exemplo:

Eu rodo:

```
ssh -p port user@host
```

E então isso pede a senha, como na próxima linha eu faço pra responder isso programaticamente no mesmo .bat?

Eu tentei:

```
ssh -p port user@host
PASSWORD
```

Mas não funciona, ele descarta minha senha e exige-a na próxima linha.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que

```
echo PASSWORD | ssh -p port user @ host
```

serve pro que você quer

Comment: Não sei se pra esse meu caso específico não funciona, mas qnd rodo isso, dá um erro: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` e depois vai como se tivesse rodado apenas o `ssh -p port user @ host`

Comment: não sei se vai funcionar mas tenta isso -> echo PASSWORD | ssh -tt -p port user @ host